# Redis test isn't working - this test method is being called multiple times instead of being cached after the first

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, mockito

I'm learning Spring Boot and have built a simple RESTful API. In this API I'm just simply adding "student" information. Every test runs successfully except for the test in the StudentConfigTest.java file. When I run this test, I'm calling the studentRepository.findAll() method twice. The first time should invoke the repository, cache the data, and in the second call instead of invoking the method again, it should just return the data from the cache. Below are all of the related files:

StudentConfigTest.java:

```
package com.example.springApi.student;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.redis.DataRedisTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
@EnableCaching
@DataRedisTest
@Import(StudentService.class)
public class StudentConfigTest {

    @MockBean
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        cacheManager.getCache("studentCache").clear();
    }

    @Test
    void givenRedisCaching_whenGetStudents_thenStudentsReturnedFromCache() {
        // Given
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
                new Student("Alice", 25, "alice@example.com"),
                new Student("Bob", 30, "bob@example.com")
        );
        given(studentRepository.findAll()).willReturn(students);

        // When
        List<Student> studentsCacheMiss = studentService.getStudents();
        List<Student> studentsCacheHit = studentService.getStudents();

        // Then
        assertThat(studentsCacheMiss).isEqualTo(students);
        assertThat(studentsCacheHit).isEqualTo(students);

        // Verify that the repository method was called only once during cache miss
        verify(studentRepository, times(1)).findAll();

        // Additional assertion to check caching behavior
        assertThat(studentService.getStudents()).isEqualTo(students); // Cache hit again, should return the same list
    }
}
```

StudentRepository.java:

```
package com.example.springApi.student;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.email = ?1")
    Optional selectExistsEmail(String email);
}
```

StudentConfig.java:

```
package com.example.springApi.student;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class StudentConfig {
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
        return (builder) -> builder
                .withCacheConfiguration("studentCache",
                        RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(10)));
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.error.include-message=always
spring.data.redis.host=localhost
spring.data.redis.port=6379
```

StudentService.java:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }
    @Cacheable("studentCache")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }
    public void addNewStudent(Student student){
        Optional existsEmail = studentRepository.selectExistsEmail(student.getEmail());
        if (existsEmail.isPresent()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email " + student.getEmail() + " taken");
        }
        if (!isValidName(student.getName())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("name can only contain letters");
        }

        studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public boolean isValidName(String studentName) {
        char[] chars = studentName.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(chars);
        for (char c: chars){
            if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void deleteStudent(Long studentId) {
        boolean exists = studentRepository.existsById(studentId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("student with id " + studentId + " does not exist");
        }
        studentRepository.deleteById(studentId);

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I put all of the relevant information above. Ignore this.

Comment: I don't see the method that should be `@Cacheable`.

Comment: @LejdiPrifti sorry about that I included the code that shows the method which has the Cacheable annotation